# Renaming Documents as specific text within document

Tags: vba, ms-word, save, rename

So I have in excess of 800 documents needing to be renamed. They all contain a specific section called 'title:' Within them. The issue is, this appears at different places throughout each document. Its basically the text afterwards that I am looking to name it.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strDoc As String
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordDoc As Word.document

Set wordApp = New Word.Application
wordApp.Visible = True

Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fd
.Title = "D:\Test\"
If .Show = -1 Then
    strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
Else
    MsgBox "You did not select the folder that contains the documents."
    Exit Sub
End If
End With

MkDir strFolder & "Processed"

strDoc = Dir$(strFolder & "*.docx")
While strDoc <> ""
Set wordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(strFolder & strDoc)
With wordDoc
    .Content.Select
    With wordApp.Selection.Find
        .Text = "Your establishment name [0-9]{4}"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
    End With
    .SaveAs strFolder & "Processed\" & Right(wordApp.Selection, 4) & ".docx"
    .Close
End With
strDoc = Dir$()
Wend

wordApp.Quit
Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I found some code done by Silkroad, that appears todo exactly as I want it to do but it errors.

This basically errors at the line With wordApp.Selection.Find:

> runtime error 91: object variable
>   or with block variable not set

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't `Word.Documents` be `wordApp.Documents`? Seems `wordApp.Selection` would remain `Nothing` otherwise, which explains how `With wordApp.Selection.Find` would throw that error.

Comment: Great spot! Well its attempting to run now, lets see if it manages to pull the information I want it to! Fingers crossed!

Comment: So rather than renaming them, its opening them and then having a meltdown about it. Although its managing to locate the word 'title:' Which I want it to. But I want it to pull the information after that header. Eugh.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
With wordDoc
    .Content.Select
   'With wordApp.Selection.Find (Remove this line)
      ' Add the  wordApp.Selection.Find as below
    wordApp.Selection.Find.Text = "Your establishment name [0-9]{4}"
    wordApp.Selection.Find.MatchWildcards = True
    wordApp.Selection.Find.wrap = wdFindStop
    wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute
   End With  (Remove this line)
.SaveAs strFolder & "Processed\" & Right(wordApp.Selection, 4) & ".docx"
.Close
End With
```

With Block within With block does not work as expected as it will always take the first with block and then the second with.
Remove one of the with and it will work fine.

Comment: Still wouldn't work, no matter what I tried. Just opens a document and then gives up!